# How to find the dates from a date range for a specific weekday in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have built an iOS app for the first time on my own. It’s a wage calculation app. Instead of entering total workdays in a text field, I want to select start date and end date of a period, select my day-off day, select public holiday dates, and I want to get total basic workdays minus days-off and public holidays calculated for me. How do I get a list/array of dates for a selected day within a date range? I've attached the code for my app. `

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var basicDays = ""
    @State private var lateEntry = ""
    @State private var absentDays = ""
    @State private var otHours = ""
    @State private var midNights = ""
    @State private var nightShifts = ""
    @State private var medAllowance = ""
    @State private var dayOffOTHours = ""
    @State private var pHolidayBasicHours = ""
    @State private var pHolidayOTHours = ""
    
    var netWage: Double {
        let monthlyBasic = 1200.00
        let dailyRate = monthlyBasic / 26
        let hourlyRate = dailyRate / 8
        let otRate = hourlyRate * 1.5
        let dayOffRate = hourlyRate * 2
        let publicHolidayRate = hourlyRate * 2
        let publicHolidayOTRate = hourlyRate * 3
        
        let basicDaysAmount = dailyRate * (Double(basicDays) ?? 0)
        let lateEntryAmount = hourlyRate * (Double(lateEntry) ?? 0)
        let absentDaysAmount = dailyRate * (Double(absentDays) ?? 0)
        let midNightAmount = 10 * (Double(midNights) ?? 0)
        let nightShiftAmount = 15 * (Double(nightShifts) ?? 0)
        let dayOffOTAmount = dayOffRate * (Double(dayOffOTHours) ?? 0)
        let publicHolidayAmount = (publicHolidayRate * (Double(pHolidayBasicHours) ?? 0)) + (publicHolidayOTRate * (Double(pHolidayOTHours) ?? 0))
        
        let totalOTAmount = otRate * (Double(otHours) ?? 0)
        let holidayOTAmount = dayOffOTAmount + publicHolidayAmount
        let otAmount = totalOTAmount + holidayOTAmount
        
        let totalDeduction = lateEntryAmount + absentDaysAmount
        let allowances = midNightAmount + nightShiftAmount
        
        let totalWage = basicDaysAmount + allowances + otAmount
        let netWage = totalWage - totalDeduction
        
        return netWage
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Group {
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of basic days")) {
                        TextField("", text: $basicDays)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                        
                    Section(header: Text("Enter late entries in hours")) {
                        TextField("", text: $lateEntry)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of days absent")) {
                        TextField("", text: $absentDays)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of OT hours worked")) {
                        TextField("", text: $otHours)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of Mid nights worked")) {
                        TextField("", text: $midNights)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of night shifts worked")) {
                        TextField("", text: $nightShifts)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter medical bill amount")) {
                        TextField("", text: $medAllowance)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of hours worked on days-off")) {
                        TextField("", text: $dayOffOTHours)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of public holidays worked in total hours")) {
                        TextField("", text: $pHolidayBasicHours)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    Section(header: Text("Enter number of OT hours worked on public holidays")) {
                        TextField("", text: $pHolidayOTHours)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                }
                
                Section{}

                Section {
                    Text("\(netWage, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My Wage")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}`
```

Comment: Take a look at [enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293661-enumeratedates) of `Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for, but it seems like you're saying you want to pick a date and find out what days are in period round that date.  Here's some code:

```
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "October 21, 2021") {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    let datesInWeek = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfYear, for: date)
    if let datesInWeek = datesInWeek {
        print("week from:")
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: datesInWeek.start))
        print("to:")
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: datesInWeek.end))
    }
}
```

The code takes the date "October 21, 2021" and uses `dateInterval(of:for:)` to calculate the days that are in the week surrounding that date.  This will print out:

```
week from: 
Oct 17, 2021 
to: 
Oct 24, 2021
```

**NOTE:** Your computer could come up with different dates depending on the Locale.  I'm in the US and the US typically assumes Sunday to be the first day of the week.  As I understand it, in Europe, Monday is usually the first day of the week.  So If you get different dates with this same code, it might be because your locale is different.

Comment: `"I want to select start date and end date of a period"`. What does your post has to do with what is being asked?

Comment: `"How do I get a list/array of dates for a selected day within a date range?"` My response returns the start date, and the end date, of a period (in this case the period of "a week") that contains a particular day.